# How to find the count of name that have multiple periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have a table(PERSON) that contain file names `ammu.docx`, `gopu.ammu.docx`, `veena.docx`, `maya.ammu.docx` etc...

I would like to get the count of file having multiple periods. Here (g`opu.ammu.docx`, `maya.ammu.docx`) is 2.

Please help me to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the periods and look at the change in length;

```
select *
from t
where len(f) - len(replace(f, '.', '')) > 1
```

or

```
where f like '%.%.%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 WHERE
   LEN(FileNameColumn) >= LEN(REPLACE(FileNameColumn, '.', '')+2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    LEN(REPLACE(ColumnName, '.', '')) as NumberOfDots,
    COUNT (*)
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE NumberOfDots > 1
```

Not 100% about syntax as its untested but this should be there or there abouts.